# I am signing (HMAC) outgoing webhooks to allow users to verify their source, should I also sign outgoing responses?

Tags: authentication, api, hmac

To allow api users to verify the authenticity of outgoing webhooks, I am using a similar model to slack:

- Concatenate timestamp and body, HMAC with pre-shared key, add timestamp and HMAC digest to headers.
- Recipient does the same, and compares to the digest in the header.

I can either implement this exclusively on outgoing webhooks, or I can implement it as middleware that performs this process on both outgoing webhooks, and responses to requests.

Is doing the latter good practice? A good idea?

Answer (score 0):

## This is a bad idea.

You are essentially (ab)using symmetric cryptography to implement asymmetric cryptography. In your approach, the following problems will arise:

- If you only have one key, then every client you distribute the key to can effectively impersonate you
- If you have one key per client, you need to worry about key generation, storage, exchange, deprecation, etc.

A much better idea would be to use any asymmetric cipher (Elliptic Curves, RSA, etc.). The scheme would then work as follows:

- You generate a private and public key pair, and distribute the public key.
- You sign the timestamp and body, then send it off to your client(s).
- The client(s) use your public key to verify the signature, and thus both the authenticity and integrity of the message.

Comment: I would use one key per client, but I only have three clients. From the reading that I’ve done, HMAC always seems to be done with symmetric keys, and slack seems to use it for their outgoing web hooks. Have I misunderstood that process?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using HTTPS (or some other protocol protected by TLS or similar security), **you don't need to sign responses**. The purpose of the signature is to protect the integrity of the message (already handled by TLS) and the authenticate the sender of the message (already handled by TLS). It does make sense to sign the requests, because by default HTTPS only authenticates the server (the party that receives requests and sends responses).

This is why, when you log into Google or similar, you supply your credentials (username+password+any additional factors), but the server doesn't have to add any signature to their responses that you must then verify. Authentication of the server is handled at the TLS layer, between your browser (or other client) and their server.

Client authentication in HTTPS *is* possible, and would be substantially more secure than the signing scheme you're currently using. This is known as "mutual TLS" (or just "mTLS") or "TLS with client certificates", and requires that the client (in this case, your software that generates webhook callbacks; even if you think of it as a "server" it is a client for the purpose of those requests) authenticate itself to the user's servers using its own certificate. The user's servers would need to be configured to expect this certificate, which almost all web server software supports but sometimes isn't easy to set up. However, it provides better protection than the system you've described, without requiring either that the other party be able to impersonate you, or that you have a unique pre-shared key for each user.